# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, angular8, http-options-method

> I'm trying to make a connection with node.js and when trying to use the .map it informs that the property does not exist, but the imports description here are correct

[image]

Comment: I think you want to use `.then`, not `.map`.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask): if you have code to show, paste actual code. Don't use an image. And use normal formatting: why did you quote your own text?